# Undertow throws RuntimeException when uploading multipart file exceeding the setting value

Tags: java, spring-boot, undertow

I'm running the complete version of Spring boot Upload file guide at [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/), but I used Undertow as embedded servlet instead of Tomcat default. And it worked.

When I try to upload file with size larger than the value in config file

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
```

It raises exception. That is expected behavior

With Tomcat embedded servlet, it can be easily handled by catching `SizeLimitExceededException` or `MultipartException`

But with Undertow, it throws RuntimeException event I catch it in global handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler({RuntimeException.class, Exception.class, IOException.class})
    ResponseEntity<?> handleControllerException(Exception exc, HttpServletRequest request, Throwable ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

The Exception message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 131072
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:779) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.20.Final.jar:1.4.20.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameter(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:653) ~[undertow-servlet-1.4.20.Final.jar:1.4.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
```

Here is the codes:

The controller

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    storageService.store(file);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-uploading-files</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anyone get the same problem with me? How can I catch the exception when maximum file size upload is exceeded?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It looks like a bug to me (in spring-boot probably) that exceptions from violating spring.http.multipart.max-file-size a catchable with ExceptionHandler with one conainer and not with other...

Comment: It looks that spring-boot correctly maps the spring properties to the servlet spec properties, and the limits apply correctly to both tomcat and undertow. 

HttpServletRequest.getParts() contract defines that an IllegalStateException should be thrown when maxFileSize or maxRequestSize is reached, which is wrapped in a MultipartException by spring. This contact is not followed by undertow, which results in throwing an error at a different point, which is not handled by spring, so the exception escapes from the framework and not handled by any defined @ExceptionHandler method.

Comment: I also raised an issue on undertow jira. You can follow it here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1227

Comment: I am running into the same issue. It looks like the issue that  @YannisSermetziadis raised has been resolved in `1.4.22.Final` however after upgrading Spring Boot & Undertow I am still struggling to catch this exception in my `@ControllerAdvice`. 

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: io.undertow.server.RequestTooBigException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 15728640` 

Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @PatrickBray, Have you found the solution for the same?

Comment: No sorry @PatelRomil we ended up switching back to tomcat after running into a seperate file descriptor leak issue with multi part uploads

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is able to help in some particular case.

I have the same problem with undertow and exception handling.

My case is a little bit different, I also have spring-security, so the exceptions like `RequestTooBigException` are caused in spring-security filters when some of them try to read information from the request.

As a solution, I use an additional filter that is added before the first security filter that is caused that exception. (For my it is `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class`)

There is an additional filter that handles these exceptions:

```java
 @Component
 @Slf4j
 public class SecurityRequestToBigExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   @Override
   public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
       FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
     try {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
     } catch (IllegalStateException | RequestTooBigException | MultiPartParserDefinition.FileTooLargeException ex) {

       if (ex instanceof RequestTooBigException
           || ex instanceof MultiPartParserDefinition.FileTooLargeException) {
         writeResponse(response, ex);
         return;
       }

       Throwable causeException = ex.getCause();
       if (nonNull(causeException)
           && (causeException instanceof RequestTooBigException
           || causeException instanceof MultiPartParserDefinition.FileTooLargeException)) {
         writeResponse(response, causeException);
         return;
       }

       throw ex;
     }
   }

   private void writeResponse(HttpServletResponse response, Throwable ex) throws IOException {
     log.debug("Handle RequestToBig Exception with {}", ex.getMessage());
     response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
     response.getWriter().write(ex.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Next what we need to change is security configuration.

There is my simplified security config:

```java
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   private final SecurityRequestToBigExceptionHandlerFilter requestToBigExceptionHandlerFilter;

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http 
         .addFilterBefore(requestToBigExceptionHandlerFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class)
         .csrf().disable()
         .cors()
         .and()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
   }
 }
```